# (Lyx) How can I write next to a picture at the top

Tags: lyx

[image]

When I start to want to write something next to the picture I am always at the bottom next to the picture but want to start at the top, does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Text is aligned to the baseline, which is `\ht\strutbox` below the top and `\dp\strutbox` above the bottom.  `\includegraphics` puts the baseline at the bottom.  You can use `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to add alignment options, or use `\raisebox`.

Comment: Does Insert > Float > Figure Wrap Float do what you want?